# javascript es6 module class include in head

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following class file:

```
export default class test
{
    constructor()
    {
        console.log('ok');
    }
}
```

When I bundle this up with babel/gulp as an es6 module, I simply can do

```
import 'test' from 'test';
const t = new test();
```

I also want to provide that library for including it the traditional way with

```
<script src="test.min.js"></script>
const t = new test();
```

I bundle up test.min.js with browserify, I can also get this to work only when I add

```
window.test = test;
```

to the bottom of the class file and

```
const t = new window.test();
```

when calling it.

Is there a way around the window. prefix, especially when calling?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `const t = new window.test();` are you sure about this? window is the highest scope, so after setting `window.test = test;` in your script, test should be a global variable and available as `const t = new test();`. There isn't a way afaik to avoid this, since import/export is explicitly made to NOT set global scope. Could you give more info about why it has to be global? When using the babel/gulp/browserify combination, I just transform all the `import 'test' from 'test';` syntax into `const test = require( 'test' );` so it can be imported into non-ES6 as well.

Comment: Did you read this: https://github.com/umdjs/umd

Comment: Browserify should have an option to add these export-to-global-scope lines automatically.

Comment: @Shilly: Yes, window.test = test is inside the class file, so this should be another scope.